# Set the order of JSON properties serialized from a third-party object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am serializing objects to JSON for which I do not own the code (so I cannot set the `[JsonProperty(Order = x)]` attribute on each property).

I also need to specify only certain properties to be serialized.

The following code is working, but I need to also specify the order of the properties.

```
public class DynamicContractResolver : Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver
{
    private IList<string> _propertiesToSerialize = null;

    public DynamicContractResolver(IList<string> propertiesToSerialize)
    {
        _propertiesToSerialize = propertiesToSerialize;
    }

    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization); //.OrderBy(p => p.Order).ToList();
        return properties.Where(p => _propertiesToSerialize.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();
    }
}

//...

List<string> propertiesToSerialize = new List<string>(new string[]
{
    "name",
    "masterString",
    "cruiseMode",
    "account"
});

DynamicContractResolver contractResolver = new DynamicContractResolver(propertiesToSerialize);

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_objToSerialize, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
    new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = contractResolver });
```

The output is:

```
{
  "masterString": "Provider...",
  "cruiseMode": 2,
  "account": "xxx\yyy",
  "name": "AdWorksName"
}
```

But I need it to be:

```
{
  "name": "AdWorksName",
  "masterString": "Provider...",
  "cruiseMode": 2,
  "account": "xxx\yyy",
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the [JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) technically defines an object as "an unordered set of name/value pairs", JSON.net will still allow you to set the order of the properties if you want.  In your resolver, you just need to set the `Order` values on each `JsonProperty` and then return them sorted accordingly.

```
protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization)
        .Where(p => _propertiesToSerialize.Contains(p.PropertyName)).ToList();

    foreach (JsonProperty prop in properties)
    {
        prop.Order = _propertiesToSerialize.IndexOf(prop.PropertyName) + 1;
    }

    return properties.OrderBy(p => p.Order).ToList();
}
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OhfWHl

Comment: That worked!  And such an easy solution too.  Thanks Brian!

Comment: No problem; glad to help.

Answer (score -1):

The order of properties is not meaningful or maintained in JSON, for the same reasons the order of attributes is not maintained in XML ... or in Javascript itself. If you want ordering, it has to be serialized as a list.